# how i can get comment by FBQL or curl in my page facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have page in facebook 
and i want develop php control panel to mange comment 
1- display all comment in uploaded image
2- display all comment in wall 
how i can get all comment by 
1- FBQL
2 -curl  (Especially that Facebook does not appear all the comments appear only penalty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with curl using facebook graph api.

```
$page_id = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";
$page_access_token = "";
$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
    if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
        $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
        break;
    }
}
```

After you've got the access token for your page, use graph api to view your wall:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/$pageid/feed?accesstoken=page_access_token
```

and view photos and their comments:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/$pageid/photos?accesstoken=page_access_token
```

for more information use  [facebooks official graph api documentation for pages.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

Comment: While you are correct that it's using "curl" but here you are using the [PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) (curl is used in the background). also it's worth mentioning that you've got the code from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326537/post-on-a-facebook-wall-as-page-not-as-user/5327561#5327561).

Comment: @ifaour - you're absolutely right. Did i do something wrong? did i steal the code? do these 8 lines of code have copyrights?

Comment: @T4u: While **I** offer my code here for free here in SO, as I said "it's *worth mentioning* where did you get the code from". and no, no one said that you "stole" the code!

Comment: @T4u: and these are 9 lines, not 8 :-)

Comment: @ifaour, lol im sorry. you are absolutely right. by the way, i took the code from another post - and the writer did not mention you. while i usually mention the writers of the code, i didnt think these [b]9[/b] lines of code needed this mentioning. by the way, i took the code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764624/facebook-post-users-wall/5764695#5764695 .
Cheers, your code is famous! :)

Comment: @T4u: It's really nice to see some of my snippets are being used by users :-) It means that I actually gave something back to this great community!

Comment: nice answer Is the work of the same subject in the group by the same way.?