# Posting on Facebook Wall: Author name

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've created a tool which allows authors of a Typo3 site to publish wall entries on a given facebook profile or page out of the backend. This works very well, however in case of using facebook pages I encountered some trouble I could not yet solve.

Using my development account I've created a page to which's wall I'd like to post. No problem so far. The issue here: Instead of the admin's account name I'd like to see the name of the page above the wall post just like when posting a message being directly on the page.

The attached screenshot visualizes the problem.

--

[image: Current display of wall posts.]

--

Any idea what could be done to solve the issue? Thank you very much :)

cu
Roman

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post on a Facebook wall as Page, not as user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326537/post-on-a-facebook-wall-as-page-not-as-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Page's access token and not the User's access token in order for the author of wall posts to be the Page.  You'll first need the following 2 permissions from the user:

- publish_stream
- manage_pages

With those two permissions, you can get a list of all of the pages that the user is an admin of, along with the Page's access token with the following request:

```
GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={user_access_token}
```

You'll get a result like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": PAGE_NAME,
         "category": "Product/service",
         "id": PAGE_ID,
         "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
      }
   ]
}
```

Once you have the Page's access_token, you can now Publish to the Page's wall as follows:

```
POST URL: https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed
POST BODY: access_token={page_access_token}&message=Test+Post
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thats the key! Thank you very very much.