# post to facebook as PAGE - NOT as a user

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I am trying to upload an image and post to my fan page wall as a `page` using [this tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/)

however the connection doesnt seem to work. 
 
any suggestions how to get the page parameters so that i can post images to the pages wall please

this code has been modified from the latest SDK 3.1.1

```
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '***************',
    'secret' => '********************************',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $page_id = '***************';
        $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
        if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
                $args = array(
                        'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
                        'message'       => "I'm a Page!"
                );
                $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array( 'next' => 'http://myDoamin.com/logout_page.php' ));
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <title>php-sdk</title>
        <style>
            body { font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
            h1 a {  text-decoration: none; color: #3b5998; }
            h1 a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>php-sdk</h1>

        <?php if ($user): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div>
                Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
                <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <h3>PHP Session</h3>
        <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

        <?php if ($user): ?>
            <h3>You</h3>
            <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

            <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
            <pre><?php print_r($page_info); ?></pre>
        <?php else: ?>
            <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
        <?php endif ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

uploading handeled here:

```
<?php
$app_id = "***************";
$app_secret = "********************************";
$post_login_url = "http://mydomain.com/upload.php";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

//Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
if(empty($code)){ 
    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
     . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
     . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
     .  "&scope=publish_stream";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url 
    . "'</script>");
 }
else {
    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
     . "client_id=" . $app_id 
. "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url )
     . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
     . "&code=" . $code;
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];

 // Show photo upload form to user and post to the Graph URL
 $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
 . "access_token=" .$access_token;

 echo '<html><body>';
 echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
 .$graph_url .' "method="POST">';
 echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
 echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
 echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
 echo '<input name="message" 
         type="text" value=""><br/><br/>';
 echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>';
 echo '</form>';
 echo '</body></html>';
}
?>
```

the example from the `SDK` is similar and when i run this it works as user.  but not as page

```
    if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326537/post-on-a-facebook-wall-as-page-not-as-user?rq=1

Comment: i did exactly as the tutorial and the SO post described in my code above, but still it doesnt work.  what am i overlooking!?!?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I didn't realize the tutorial you linked was the one I also linked. If you run that first page, does it show you as logged in?

Comment: @JimmySawczuk no it doesnt,  also added a note to the bottom of my question.  also the SO post talks about `/me/accounts` but i didnt see anything like this in the code

Comment: So are you sure you've authenticated? Nothing jumps out at me from the code you've posted, apart from the fact that you might not have installed the app.

Comment: i seem to be able to post to a user account, just not to my fan page account

Comment: Print the data you put into `$page_info`. Does it match what you expect? If you use the [Graph API explorer and view `/me/accounts`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts) for your app, is it the same token?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13682/discussion-between-t-q-and-jimmy-sawczuk)

Comment: you will need to get a page access token for the page you wish to upload as and instead of posting to "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"  post to "https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/photos"

Comment: @ShawnECarter now im getting: `"message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: pageid",`

Comment: pageid needs to be the id or username of your actual page.  You need to change that as needed.  What is the id?

example my page is fb.com/anotherfeed  my page id is 135669679827333
my page username is anotherfeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

1. Grant `manage_pages` permissions to your application.
2. Get `page_access_token`, make api post to page as page with page token.

---

---

**EXAMPLE:**  `php cURL upload`:  stand alone example, no sdk needed.

```
<?php 
function GetCH(){
// id of the album to upload
$ablum_id = "182325958494028";
// photo caption
$photo_caption = "testing app ablum upload";
// the page access token if you are uploading as the page
$page_access_token = "Add Your page token here.";
// url to your photo
$photo_url = "http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/544288_10150906170859577_732484576_9506566_417314835_n.jpg";
//
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/".$ablum_id."/photos?url=".urlencode($photo_url)."&message=".urlencode($photo_caption)."&method=post&access_token=".$page_access_token."");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$sendCH = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $sendCH;
};

// call our function and upload photo, large photos may be slow
echo GetCH();
// if successful a return is shown
// { "id": "387851721274783", "post_id": "171535666239724_387851741274781" }
?>
```

Comment: how do i get `PAGE_ID`? keep getting `"message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: PAGE_ID"` my first part of the code calls for `manage_pages,publish_stream`

Comment: you need to manually add your Facebook pages id, the one you wish to post to,  if you link me to your page i will edit in the id of the page for you.

Comment: the 2 sets of code posted is what i am using.  where would i manually add it in?

Comment: the code above is just a segment of the code you posts.  All you are changing in your code is.

 $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
 . "access_token=" .$access_token;

Comment: you are changing /me/photos to YOUR_PAGE_ID/photos  /me  targets the current session user so you have to change that target.

Comment: i changed `PAGE_ID` to the username and now i get this: `"message": "(#240) This user isn't allowed to upload photos to this object's wall",` but inside my app setting i have `Posts on your behalf: 
Who can see posts this app makes for you on your Facebook profile? 
Everyone`

Comment: i will hang out in chat for a few hours today, if you come back just come in.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I post as a Page. I'm using [Facebook's PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/).

I am first fetching a list of all the pages the user has access to, then I present a list of them to the user so they can choose one (code not shown here). I then store that data and use it later to post as that page.

How I get the list of pages:

```
try {
        $result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
        $userpages = $result['data'];
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $userpages = array();
        $fbuser = null;
        $facebook->clearPersistentData();
}
```

Now I iterate through them (`$settings` is an array with my user's settings, including the page they chose to post as):

```
foreach ($userpages as $userpage) {
        if ($userpage['category'] == "Application")
                continue;    # My app doesn't work with Application pages.
        if ($settings['page']['id'] == $userpage['id']) {
                # This is the page I want.
                # $userpage['access_token'] has the access token.
        }
}
```

The `access_token` gets added into my array of postdata for the request, and the `id` is used here.

```
return $facebook->api("/$id/feed/", "post", $postdata);
```

Comment: i really like this example to feed Michael.

Comment: Not coincidentally, this is the way [Facebook recommends](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) you do it.