# Can a facebook app publish on behalf of a facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post on a Facebook wall as Page, not as user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326537/post-on-a-facebook-wall-as-page-not-as-user)

Can facebook apps publish on behalf of pages like they do with user statuses?

Comment: @ifa - was searching high and low for an appropriate dupe :P Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most certainly can! Just be sure to use the appropriate `access_token`. You'll need to authenticate as a page to get this. The [documentation explains it best](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/) but basically, the administrator of the page must first grant the application the `manage_pages` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/), once you have this permission, your application will be able to make an API call to `/me/accounts` to get a list of all the pages that user administers and their appropriate access tokens.

With your shiny new page access token, making calls to the API is just the same as it would be for a user -

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN&message=Hello Page World!`

Answer (score -1):

As effective from October 3, Facebook has changed some rules because of many "spamming" apps, phasing out some of previous privilages. Currently there are very limited resources/tutorials explaining this in detail but better you can check facebook API. 
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Comment: This **is** actually possible. No changes were made to policies regarding these issues... Exactly what change are you referring to?